# Can anyone recognize this subtitles editor?

Tags: subtitles, sound-editing

What is the name of the software used in the monitor on the right?

[image]

Comment: Does it make me sad that I recognize the show in the monitor on the left?

Comment: I don't know, does it?

Comment: @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams: No, that's not sad. I'm glad you can recognize it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .ass extracted from the video says [Aegisub](http://www.aegisub.org/).